# How to find email read-rate?

Tags: email, html-email

I need to figure out the time for which an email remains open at the recipient's end.
I can use a 1x1 image to find out if the email has been opened but i can't think of any way in which that would allow me to calculate the time for which the email remains open

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.

The closest you can get is by having an image never load.  That is, you accept the connection on the server, send the response headers, but don't send any data.  The client will disconnect once the e-mail is closed.  However, this is extremely problematic.  Some clients will never disconnect.  Others will timeout.  In addition, you have the problem that many won't open the image at all.  Finally, this will break many up-stream proxies.

Comment: Is there some other method where i can achieve my goal without using images?
I found a few services on google that offered this facility, do they do what you've said?

Comment: @BinoyDalal, No, there isn't.  Any services that claim they can are lying to you, or using sampling from the folks that view the "web version" of the e-mail.

Comment: i read on another post that facebook uses audio  files to perform the same activity. would it possible to use this technique to measure the open duration? more specifically, does the email service stream the entire audio from the server without any interaction from the user, or does the user need to click a link in order to do so?

Comment: @BinoyDalal Most e-mail clients, web-based included, do not download anything from any server without user interaction.  This is to prevent spam bots from knowing which e-mail addresses are real.  Audio file, image file, it doesn't matter.  They all suffer from the exact same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Brad mentions, the only other I can think to calculate time data is if they click a link in your email. You could track the time between image load (open) and click to give you some engagement data. This would obviously only return results for users who both turn on images and click a link however.

I know [Litmus has engagement tracking](https://litmus.com/email-analytics) in their analytics, not sure which technique they use to produce their results, but they only track up to 12-18 seconds.

Comment: litmus says on their site that they do this using some form of html code that the user copy pastes into his/her email
i am not aware of any such html that can be used. does anything come to your mind?

Comment: Litmus code: (id info replaced by ###): `<style>@media print{#_t { background-image: url('https://###.emltrk.com/###?p&d=[email]');}} div.OutlookMessageHeader {background-image:url('https://###.emltrk.com/###?f&d=[email]')} table.moz-email-headers-table {background-image:url('https://###.emltrk.com/###?f&d=[email]')} blockquote #_t {background-image:url('https://###.emltrk.com/###?f&d=[email]')} #MailContainerBody #_t {background-image:url('https://###.emltrk.com/###?f&d=[email]')}
</style>
<div id="_t">
</div>
<img src="https://###.emltrk.com/###?d=[email]" width="1" height="1" border="0" />`

Comment: Comment continued... As you'll see it is all just images and media queries designed to determine which client is opening the email.

Comment: i read on another post that facebook uses audio files to perform the same activity. would it possible to use this technique to measure the open duration? more specifically, does the email service stream the entire audio from the server without any interaction from the user, or does the user need to click a link in order to do so?